# VIM - How to append current line number into key mapping?

Tags: vim

I have this mapping in `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F2> :w!<CR>:!rspec %<CR>
```

Which saves the current file and runs it in console with rspec.

How do I map another key to add current line to the end like this?

```
nnoremap <F3> :w!<CR>:!rspec %:<current_line_number><CR>
```

All I could find is CTRL+G which shows current position. But can't figure out how to turn it into mapping.

Comment: there are ways to have line number in mappint, e.g. `line('.')` with `<expr>` but I don't understand what do you want to do...

Comment: So what would it look like? I want it to run a command `rspec <path to current file>:<line number in vim>` in terminal when I hit <F3>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would you do that when typing the command-line? Probably with `:help c_CTRL-R_=` to insert an expression. Well, there you have the first option:

```
nnoremap <F3> :w!<CR>:!rspec %:<C-r>=line('.')<CR><CR>
```

Alternatively, you can evaluate the line number into the command with `:execute`:

```
nnoremap <F3> :w!<CR>:!execute 'rspec %:' . line('.')<CR>
```